# Xcode crashed and closed suddenly in Playground wenn using MKLookAroundSnapshotter

Tags: swift, xcode, swift5, swift-playground

can someone tell me what the problem of this code is? In this code I tried to read the addresses from an Excel file and using CLGeocoder to store the coordinates of these addresses in CoordinateWithAddress. In the next step, I wanted to enter these coordinates into the snapshotImage function and save a photo for each saved coordinate.

when I run the program, no errors occur and it runs but suddenly Xcode crashes  and closes after saving a photo or 2.

for one coordinate everything works but if i throw everything in for loop and let it run for 1000 coordinates then Xcode suddenly closes.

```
import Foundation
import CoreLocation
import TabularData
import MapKit
import UIKit



guard let path = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "tst1", withExtension: "csv")
else{
    throw NSError()
    }
    

//let fileContent = try String(contentsOf: path, encoding: .utf8)
//let rows = fileContent.components(separatedBy: "\n")

let cleanString = try! String(contentsOf: path).trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)

let rows = cleanString.components(separatedBy: "\n")

var coordinates:[CLLocationCoordinate2D] = []

let group = DispatchGroup()

var coordinatesWithAddress : [(latitude: Double, longitude: Double,address: String)] = []


for row in rows {
    group.enter()
    sleep(2)
    let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
    geocoder.geocodeAddressString(row) { (placemarks, error) in
        guard let placemark = placemarks?.first, let location = placemark.location else {
            print("Error geocoding address: \(row)")

            group.leave()
            return
        }
        coordinatesWithAddress.append((latitude: location.coordinate.latitude,
                                      longitude: location.coordinate.longitude,address: row))
        group.leave()
   }
}



group.notify(queue: .main){
    
    
    var csvText = "latitude,longitude,address\n"
    for coordinate in coordinatesWithAddress {
        let newLine = String(format: "%f,%f,%@\n", coordinate.latitude, coordinate.longitude,coordinate.address )
        
        csvText.append(newLine)
    }
    
    do {
        if let directory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first {
            let fileName = "coordinates.csv"
            let fileURL = directory.appendingPathComponent(fileName)
            try csvText.write(to:fileURL, atomically: true, encoding: .utf8)
            print("file saved successfully")
        
        }
        
    } catch {
        print("error saving file : \(error)")
    }

}

enum LookaroundError: Error {
    case unableToCreateScene
}

func snapshotImage(for coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) async throws -> UIImage {
    guard let scene = try await MKLookAroundSceneRequest(coordinate: coordinate).scene else {
        throw LookaroundError.unableToCreateScene
    }
    let options = MKLookAroundSnapshotter.Options()
    options.size = CGSize(width: 512, height: 512)
    return try await MKLookAroundSnapshotter(scene: scene, options: options).snapshot.image
}

enum getLocationError : Error {
    case unableToGetLocation
}

sleep(5)

for coordinate in coordinatesWithAddress {

    sleep(2)

    var image = try await snapshotImage(for: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: coordinate.latitude, longitude: coordinate.longitude))

    var url = try FileManager.default.url(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
        .appending(component: "\(coordinate.address).png")
    try image.pngData()?.write(to: url)

}
```

Comment: You are making an asynchronous call in the loop so doing 1000 of them in a very quick succession might very well be the reason for the crash.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson do U have any ideas  how can i correct this problem?

Comment: Not really, find some way to throttle the calls or only make one at a time or try moving to a Xcode project instead of working in a playground.